# Understanding Regular Grammers

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

I know a regular language is the one which can be expressed as a regular expression or we can create a DFA corresponding to it. Unless a language has a pattern in which one part has to match with other like in $$a^nb^n|n\geq 0 (CFG)$$ It'll be regular. Like AP Series of symbols can be easily expressed as Regular expression but GP Series can not.

But I failed to understand why the following languages are regular

> $L_1=\{wxw^R \mid w,x \in (a,b)^+\}$
>
> $L_2=\{wxwy \mid w,x,y \in (a,b)^+\}$
>
> $L_3=\{xwyw \mid w,x,y \in (a,b)^+\}$

Comment: See a very similar [question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37450/three-languages-and-how-to-decide-if-they-are-regular) here, where it is explained how both $L_2$ are indeed regular, as you can take very short strings $w$.

Comment: @DaveClarke - I think all of them are regular, as $w$ could be a single letter..

Comment: You are making a confusion between languages and grammars. There are no grammars in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these languages are regular. This comes from the fact $w$ could simply be a single letter, and thus the languages admit the following regular expressions (assuming here $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$, but this would work for any finite alphabet):

$$L_1=a(a+b)^+a+b(a+b)^+b$$
$$L_2=a(a+b)^+a(a+b)^++b(a+b)^+b(a+b)^+$$
$$L_2=(a+b)^+a(a+b)^+a+(a+b)^+b(a+b)^+b$$

---

A more detailed explanation:

In the definition we had: $w\in\{a,b\}^+$.

This mean that $w$ could be a single letter, $a$, or $b$, and thus we can attribute the rest of the word to $x$ (or $y$).

For example, if:
$$u=abbababa\in L_1$$, because it can be decomposed as $w=a, x=bbabab$ and $$u=wxw^R$$. Similarly, each word which starts and ends with a $a$ is in $L_1$ (pick $w=a$), and each word that starts and ends with a $b$ is also in $L_1$ (pick $w=b$). This is why $$L_1=\{axa|x\in\{a,b\}^+\}\cup\{bxb|x\in\{a,b\}^+\}$$, and thus regular. Same tricks apply to the other languages and all three are indeed regular (by the regex I gave).

Comment: What does it mean to say 'w' can be a single letter, Please explain in details

Comment: @Atinesh, in your definition: $w\in\{a,b\}^+$. This mean that $w$ could be a single letter, $a$, or $b$, and we can attribute the rest of the word to $x$ (or $y$).
For example:
$u=abbababa\in L_1$, because it can be decomposed as $w=a, x=bbabab$ and $u=wxw^R$. Similarly, each word which starts and ends with a $a$ is in $L_1$ (pick $w=a$), and each word that starts and ends with a $b$ is also in $L_1$ (pick $w=b$). This is why $L_1=\{axa|x\in\{a,b\}^*\}\cup\{bxb|x\in\{a,b\}^*\}$, and thus regular. Same tricks apply to the other languages and all three are indeed regular (by the regex I gave).

Comment: Thanks RB now I get this concept, but lets modify the regular expression little bit suppose w,x,y belongs to (a+b)* then I think for L1 regular expression will be (a+b)* instead of a(a+b)*a+b(a+b)*b.

Comment: @Atinesh - indeed. In fact, if we require $|w|\geq k $, for any fixed $k$, this is still regular ($^*$ is $k=0$, $^+$ is $k=1$).

Comment: And what about $L_2$ and $L_3$ in case of w,x,y$\in (a+b)^*$, Do they also have RE as $(a+b)^*$

Comment: @Atinesh - of course, just pick $w=\epsilon$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20599/discussion-between-atinesh-and-r-b).

Comment: can u come in the chat If you don't mind. Just for a while. comments getting too long here

Comment: @Atinesh - sorry, I gotta get back to work :/.

Comment: Ok one last doubt suppose $w,x,y\in (a+b)^+$ then would $wxyw$ be regular and what if $w,x,y\in (a+b)^*$

Comment: @Atinesh - $wxyw$ is not regular ($wxyw^R$ does though) if $w\in\Sigma^+$. That said, if $w\in\Sigma^*$, then you can still pick $w=\epsilon$ and this becomes regular.

Comment: For the irregularity of the $^+$ case, look for the pumping-lemma proof of $\{ww|w\in\Sigma^*$, it should be almost the same.

Comment: what will be the RE for $wxyw^R | w,x,y \in (a+b)^+$

Comment: @Atinesh - regular. Pick a single letter $w$.

Comment: I'm asking for Regular expression for $wxyw^R|w,x,y \in (a+b)^+$

Comment: @Atinesh - $a(a+b)(a+b)^+a+b(a+b)(a+b)^+b$..